# Apply Button() to an element inside a variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, variables

If have a variable `data = '<div>... <button id="remember"> ... </button> ...</div>'`, is it possible to apply the `.button();` method to a button inside that variable?

I've tried the following:

```
$('#remember', data).button();
```

but that doesn't work. After that I just do `$(data).dialog();`, which works.

I've come with a workaround and that's to `append` the variable `data` to the document, call the `.button()` and then call the `.dialog()`, but appending and removing dialog's `divs` on the document doesn't seems right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`.find(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) like this

```
var data = '<div>... <button id="remember"> ... </button> ...</div>';
​$(data).find("#remember").button().end().dialog();​​​​
```

[You can see a quick demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ7xV/)

For a breakdown of how this works:

1. `$(data)` - Creates a document fragment out of your string
2. `.find("#remember")` - Locates the `<button>` inside
3. `.button()` - Creates the jQuery UI button effect on that element
4. `.end()` - Returns the previous set selector, effectively `$(data)`
5. `.dialog()` - Creates a dialog on the whole data element, since that's where `.end()` puts the chain.

Comment: Nick, one quick question, just for curiosity: after you call dialog(); what's the context of button > $('#remember', [context]) < ?

Comment: @Ben - Not sure I follow, if you mean [`.context`](http://api.jquery.com/context/), it will be undefined at that point, since no context was originally passed, you could use any context that's an ancestor after you add it to the DOM with `.dialog()` (which inserts it in a wrapped dialog just before `</body>`).  If you do `$(selector)` the context is always `document` because `$(selector)` is changed to `$(selector, document)` under the covers, really performing a `$(document).find(selector)`.  You can see the original example in the answer updated here for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/DZ7xV/1/

Comment: @Nick Craver - I was talking about the context used to select elements inside `$(data)`. I found that, after `$(data).dialog();` was called, selecting elements (on the dialog buttons functions) like this `$('#remember')` is a little buggy. Instead you should select them like this `$('#remember', $(this))`, being `$(this)` the first element of `$(data)` (the dialog div)

Comment: @Ben - That *should* only be buggy if there are multiple `#remember`, hopefully that's not the case...that'll give you all sorts of weird behavior.  Also one tip on the context, [it'll take a DOM element](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), so you can just do `$('#remember', this)`, no need to wrap `this` in a jQuery object :)

Comment: @Nick Craver - You're right, it seems that the problems occurs after I close and re-open the dialog. I've tried removing the document fragment using `$(data).remove();` but that doesn't seems to work. Firebugs tells me that the fragment is placed before the `</body>` tag. Any idea on this?

Comment: @Ben - Try `.dialog('destroy').dialog()` instead of just `.dialog()` so it removes the previous instance...though I'm not 100% sure on how the dialog reference works with a fragment, if it doesn't work I'll take a look when I return this afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>No, there is no "button" inside that variable, just a string of characters. You will have to add the button to the DOB (e.g. by using append(), as you're already doing), before you can apply a method to that element.</strike>

**Edit:** Apparently not! See comment below.

Comment: This isn't correct, jQuery allows you to create a document fragment via `$(html)` without inserting into the DOM, at least not until `.dialog()` is called.